# Bug the person don't make animation

Tags: lua, roblox

In the roblox studio the animations how run, walk, crouch, working correctly, but in the map roblox, don't make nothing animation.

I think that the animation working in the map roblox, but don't working correctly, and have a error in line 4 of "animations", in the roblox studio don't have nothing of error.

Comment: This description is a bit vague. What have you tried, where is the relevant code?